# Generate PDF forms using FOP?

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have generated pdf using xsl:fo and FOP api v1.0. But now I need to generate PDF forms i.e. there should be some static content as well as some form fields; for eg - text boxes, check box.

Are there any tags in xsl:fo that can bring in text boxes,check boxes etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is not available as part of XSL:FO, however there are some commercial vendors that provide extensions to FO that can d this (RenderX & Antennahouse are examples). Sadly, they are not in a price range that I would be willing to pay, so your mileage may vary.